# Passing multiple dimensions to google analytics API

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

How would I go about passing multiple dimensions when executing a Google Analytics API Query. For example how would I pass `ga:pagePath` in addition to `ga:hostname` in my dimensions?

```
return $analytics->data_ga->get(
      'ga:' . $profileId,
      '60daysAgo',
      'today',
      'ga:visits',
      array(
        'dimensions' => 'ga:hostname',
        'metrics' => 'ga:pageviews',
        'sort' => '-ga:pageviews',
        'max-results' => '500'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just comma separate them. For example:

```
'ga:hostname,ga:country,ga:browser'
```

Also note that in your code example, you're passing the metric `ga:visits` (which is deprecated), and then you passing `ga:pageviews` later, which I'm assuming is getting discarded, since it's not in the right place. You're then sorting on `ga:pageviews`, which probably won't work if it's being discarded.

Hope that helps.